# Streaming in a char Number

Tags: c++, stream

Is there a way to stream in a number to a unsigned char?

```
istringstream bytes( "13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20" );
unsigned char myChars[8];

for( int i = 0; i < 8 && !bytes.eof(); i++ )
{
    bytes >> myChars[i];
    cout << unsigned( myChars[i] ) << endl;
}
```

This code currently outputs the ascii values of the first 8 non-space characters:

> 49 51 49 52 49 53 49 54

But what I want is the numerical values of each token:

> 13
>   14
>   15
>   16
>   17
>   18
>   19
>   20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there is a lot of error checking that you'll bypass to do this without a temporary. For example, does each number being assigned *fit* in a byte and are there more numbers in `bytes` than elements of `myChars`? But presuming you've already delt with those you can just use an [`istream_iterator<unsigned short>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator):

```
copy(istream_iterator<unsigned short>{ bytes }, istream_iterator<unsigned short>{}, begin(myChars))
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://ideone.com/RuGvYj)

---

An additional note here: A `char[]` typically contains a null terminated string. Presuming that's not what you intend, it would be gracious of you to indicate to the reader that's not how you're using it. In [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) you were given [`int8_t`/`uint8_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) to do just that. Using something like: `uint8_t myChars[8]` would make your code more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading a `char` at a time, which means you get `'1'`, `'3'`, skips the space, `'1'`, `'4'`, skips the space, etc.

To read the values as NUMBERS, you need to use an integer type as a temporary:

```
unsigned short s;
bytes >> s;
myChars[i] = s;
```

Now, the stream will read an integer value, e.g. 13, 14, and store it in s. Then you convert it to a `unsigned char` with `myChars[i] = s;`.

Comment: Or more explicitly `myChars[i] = static_cast<char>(s)` (depending on compiler options like "treat warnings as errors" and "error level set to 3 or 4 or all"

Comment: I should have been more clear in the question. I understood my current output, but I wanted to get around making a temporary short. Though, from your response the temporary short is my only option.